# $request->content in PhpStorm is underlined as Error

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm developing a program on Laravel Framework on PhpStorm IDE. The word "content" in the following code is always underlined as Error.

Is "content" a reserved name for `$request` variable? how to solve it? This code is in the controller.

```
$review->content = $request->content;
```

Comment: well there is a `protected $content` variable on the class, but from outside the Request class it isn't accessible

Comment: @lagbox how can i tell phpstorm that it isn't an error?

Comment: @Sina___ Why not use `$request->getContent();` which is meant for accessing `content` property from outside?

Comment: @LazyOne i replaced the line with $request->input('content'); which isn't recognized as error. i want to dismiss these kinds of errors which aren't error...

Comment: So ... `content` in `$request->content` is a request parameter/variable? Then yes, you need to use `input("content")` or alike to access it. As per static analysis (and ignoring the Laravel magic) the IDE is correct here in marking `$request->content` with "accessing protected property" warning.

Comment: @Sina___ are you using form request class and `content` is one of the input fields in this class ? If it is yes, you may use annotation to eliminate error.

Comment: Do you have [laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) already installed?

Comment: @LazyOne so you are implying that input('content') is more desirable, as $request->content is correctly warned as error.  after googling a bit I found out, seeing the input() method might help immediately clarify to you that this line of code is, in fact, a form input but $request->content usage might be confusing, secondly $request->foo behavior is different and has another kind of usage... thnx everyone...  i don't know which answer as shall i check as accepted... i would accept any good summary of the whole stuff...

Comment: @Sina___ `$request->input("content")` is a very clear in what that line is doing while `$request->content` even though may provide the same result in the end, it relies on a magic methods (using `__get()`) and how Laravel handles it, even if it will be typehinted via PHPDoc. Explicit invocation is always better than implicit: for IDE (to check your code), for PHP (faster direct method call and not magic one) and for the user (no need to guess what exactly it does here).